# setting up Windows 2008 STD EN on dedicated server

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-hosting

I just purchased a dedicated server and i need to setup for hosting my website.

Please help me how do i setup the server step by step.

server details :
Windows 2008 STD EN 
SQL Server Web 2008
Core2 Quad 2.4GHz
6GB RAM
Single-Power
150GB Velociraptor 10K RPM

Please help me for :
1.Setting up server and hosting website
2.Email settings
3.How to set DNS as domain is from another host.

regards,
Sunny

Comment: Hi Sunny. You really need to ask some more specific questions rather than just please help. Your request is too broad and is bordering on the *please do my job for me*. How about you break it down into some more specific questions.

Comment: @Sim: agreed. This is a pretty big question.

@sunny: How much help do you really need? Have you set up a server before? Are you asking for these types of answers: 1. Unpack server. 2. Plug in server. 3. Put Windows DVD in DVD drive. 4. Turn on server. ?

Comment: @SIM and @joeqwerty :
1.How to set DNS which i can point them against my domain name.
2.MS access DB connection is not wrking.Code is right as wrking properly on another server.

Can you help me for these 2 specific queries.

Comment: 1: forget it. You should have 3 dns server - and only have 1 server. beteter do not use DNS On your server. Use the DNS servers of your provider, or registrar.

Comment: 2: 32 or 64 bit? Better: DO NOT USE ACCESS - instal SQL Server express.

Comment: 3: specific queries - ask on slashdot, with code example etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following ServerFault questions as a start [Dedicated Server Tutorials](https://serverfault.com/questions/62205/dedicated-server-tutorials) and [What do I need to know about running my own dedicated server (with windows 2008)](https://serverfault.com/questions/7338/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-running-my-own-dedicated-server-with-windows-2008).